# AWS Beanstalk failed to deploy Docker Node(React) app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying Dockerized React app to AWS Beanstalk.
(Type: t2.micro / Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2)
My docker image works when I run locally.(`docker run -p 3001:3000 -d todo-app`)
But when I try to deploy (`eb deploy`), failed with error message:

`ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.`
(From eb-engine.log below:)
`[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Run Docker Container]. Stop running the command. Error: open file failed with error open /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/.aws_beanstalk.current-container-id: no such file or directory`

Here is my Dockerfile (Very simple):

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And here is my Package.json (If it helps)

```
{
  "name": "todo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Could I get some hint what causes error please?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a clear reason, but there were two solutions.

Solution 1: Change platform from `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2`
to `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux (Deprecated)`.

Solution 2:
Update Node.js version from 14 to 16.
(Changing `FROM node:14-alpine` to `FROM node:16-alpine` in Dockerfile)